# Random variable function is random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

I'm starting to study random variables and during class my teacher mentioned that a non-descending random variable function is a random variable. Then he said that $|X|$ and the indicator function $I(A_x)$ would be random variables. Intuitively I can see they are. But how do I prove it in the general case, or for these two examples?

Comment: I wonder what $A_x$ means. The subscript $x$ is confusing. If it was just $I(A)$ I would assume this is an indicator for an event $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and you can prove $I(A)$ is a random variable by showing $\{I(A)\leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A cute way to show $|X|$ is a random variable, given that you know $X$ and $-X$ are random variables, is $\{|X|\leq x\} = \{X\leq x\} \cap \{-X\leq x\}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This uses more basic concepts than the fact that a continuous function of a random variable is a random variable, though the fact about continuous functions (given in the Yalikes answer) is more useful.

Answer (score 3):

As random variable (let’s consider one-dimensional case for simplicity) defined to be a measurable function from sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with corresponding $\sigma$-algebras (usually, it is Borel $\sigma$-algebra for $\mathbb{R}$).

It’s [known](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eheil/6337/spring11/section3.5.pdf) that composition of two measurable functions is again measurable, so for random variable $X$, for any measurable function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (again, with respect to Borel $\sigma$-algebra) $f(X) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is also a random variable.
In particular, all continuous $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions are measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose a non empty set $\Omega$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on it. A function $X: \Omega \to \Bbb R$ is said to be $\mathcal F$-*measurable*, if $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F$ for every Borel set $B$ (i.e. a set inside the minimum $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $\Bbb R$ or equivalently from intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$)$^1$. If $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ is a probability space, then $X$ is a *random variable*.

My suggestion about the way that one can prove that a function like the above is a random variable, is to check if the sets of the form $X^{-1}((-\infty, x])$ are contained in the given $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ for an arbitrary $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: +1, I don't know why this was downvoted. The second paragraph gives the general method that was asked for, equivalently,  you want to show $\{X\leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have really not understood what happened; I saw a +8, someone deleted the footnote  (!) and I never saw an up- or downvote!.. Thanks for your comment and information!